# Flutter Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> to Future<int>

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have the following Flutter code using SQFLite:

```
Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> countRecords() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(${Fields.Txt}) FROM $Table');
    if(result.isNotEmpty) return result; else throw Exception('Empty Result');
  }
```

Plus, I have the following code which is failing b/c I cannot assign Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> to Future int:

```
int Count = 0;

Future<int> countTableRecords() async {
    return Count = await DBHelper.instance.countRecords();
  }
```

I need to extract from sqflite db the number of records.

The expression return type must be Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>>, but
I need to return Future int:

```
final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(${Fields.Txt}) FROM $Table');
```

Could you please advise how to convert Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> to Future int.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

##### UPDATE

```dart
Future<int> countRecords() async {
  final db = await instance.dataBase;
  final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(${Fields.Txt}) FROM $Table');
  if(result.isNotEmpty) 
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(result); 
  else throw Exception('Empty Result');
}
```

##### OLD ANSWER

Try this:

```dart
Future<int> countTableRecords() async {
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await DBHelper.instance.countRecords());
}
```

Comment: The main issue is: countRecords return type is Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>>, but I need this to be: Future<int>. How would I achieve it? Thank You

Comment: Check the updated code